# MySQL: Select Last Max() Value of One Group But Summarize by Another Group

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to list the Company_Name by the last values of Date_Time for Employees and QA_Score with this dataset:

```
+--------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+----------+
| Company_Name | Wing_Name |    Date_Time     | Employees | QA_Score |
+--------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+----------+
| Company A    | Wing A    | 06/08/2018 13:00 |        82 | 3.5      |
| Company A    | Wing A    | 06/08/2018 13:01 |        83 | 3.6      |
| Company A    | Wing A    | 06/08/2018 13:02 |        84 | 3.7      |
| Company B    | Wing A    | 06/08/2018 14:00 |        82 | 3.6      |
| Company B    | Wing A    | 06/08/2018 14:01 |        85 | 3.7      |
| Company B    | Wing A    | 06/08/2018 14:02 |        88 | 3.8      |
+--------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+----------+
```

The desired output should be:

```
+--------------+-----------+----------+
| Company_Name | Employees | QA_Score |
+--------------+-----------+----------+
| Company A    |        84 | 3.7      |
| Company B    |        88 | 3.8      |
+--------------+-----------+----------+
```

I've been successful in using the following code to display the last result of Date_Time by Wing_Name but cannot for the life of me figure it out for Company_Name, while leaving Wing_Name out of the output.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (Wing_Name, Date_Time) IN
(SELECT Wing_Name, MAX(Date_Time) Date_Time FROM table GROUP BY Wing_Name)
AND `Company_Name` = "Company A";
```

This must be something simple that I am missing?
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

I believe I may have not asked my question properly and have improved the dataset listing to provide more color on the purpose of Wing_Name and my output intentions:

```
+--------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+----------+
| Company_Name | Wing_Name |    Date_Time     | Employees | QA_Score |
+--------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+----------+
| Company A    | Wing A    | 06/08/2018 13:00 |        82 | 3.5      |
| Company A    | Wing A    | 06/08/2018 13:01 |        83 | 3.6      |
| Company A    | Wing A    | 06/08/2018 13:02 |        84 | 3.7      |
| Company A    | Wing B    | 06/08/2018 13:00 |        50 | 4.1      |
| Company A    | Wing B    | 06/08/2018 13:01 |        51 | 4.2      |
| Company A    | Wing B    | 06/08/2018 13:02 |        52 | 4.3      |
| Company B    | Wing A    | 06/08/2018 14:00 |        82 | 3.6      |
| Company B    | Wing A    | 06/08/2018 14:01 |        85 | 3.7      |
| Company B    | Wing A    | 06/08/2018 14:02 |        88 | 3.8      |
+--------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+----------+
```

From this edit, the desired output should now be the sum of Employees for Company_Name through results of every Wing_name, along with the Average of QA_Score for those respective Wing_Name but summarized under Company_Name

Using the new revised dataset above, the desired output should be:

- Last Date_Time value for Employees for Company A And Wing A was 84.
- Last Date_Time value for Employees for Company A and Wing B was 52.
- Company A has 84+52 Employees (136) as of the last Date_Time retrieval.
- Last Date_Time value for QA_Score for Company A and Wing A was 3.7.
- Last Date_time value for QA_Score for Company A and Wing B was 4.3.
- Company A Average QA_Score for Company A was 4.0

> ```
> +--------------+-----------+----------+
> | Company_Name | Employees | QA_Score |
> +--------------+-----------+----------+
> | Company A    |       136 | 4        |
> | Company B    |        88 | 3.8      |
> +--------------+-----------+----------+
> ```

Comment: Looking at the expected output, it seems that you need to group by the record based on the company_name and then find maximum date records for that group. What is the role of the Wing_name here?

Comment: Company_Name has multiple Wing_Name (Wing A, Wing B, Wing C, etc...).  When values for every Wing_Name are entered into the table, it leaves a Date_Time entry at that date of retrieval, Wing A had a certain amount of Employees and a new corresponding QA_Score.

Comment: Could you please look at my edit?  I just reformulated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using similar logic as your existing sql:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (Company_Name, Date_Time) IN
(SELECT Company_Name, MAX(Date_Time) Date_Time FROM table GROUP BY Company_Name);
```

Or using a Correlated Subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t1
WHERE Date_Time = (SELECT Max(Date_Time) FROM Table WHERE t1.Company_Name = Company_Name);
```

Comment: This returns only one entry (the MAX Date_Time) for one specific Company, when I want all companies listed with their respective values using the last MAX Date_Times for appropriate Wings.

Comment: Then remove that last condition that restricts it to "Company A"...?  I just updated the answer to remove that. (I thought it was important since it was in your original SQL).

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add the company name:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE (Company_name, Wing_Name, Date_Time) IN
        (SELECT CompanyName, Wing_Name, MAX(Date_Time) Date_Time
         FROM table
         GROUP BY Company_Name, Wing_Name
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Or an uncorellated solution...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN
     ( SELECT company_name
            , wing_name
            , MAX(date_time) dt 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY company_name
            , wing_name
     ) y
    ON y.company_name = x.company_name 
   AND y.wing_name = x.wing_name 
   AND y.dt = x.date_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub-Query with `GROUP BY` and `SUM` and `AVG`look at code bellow and the sqlfiddle example is updated:

```
 select Company_Name,sum(Employees),avg(QA_Score) from Table1 where (Company_Name,Date_Time) 
    in (
    select Company_Name,Max(Date_Time)  from Table1 group by Company_Name  
    )
    group by Company_Name
```

Here an example sqlfiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/27SuaGjL3SKfxhvqRRWUdd/3